# Which update query caused org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

I am getting org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException and would like to know update of which entity caused the exception. All I get is exception with the entity name and Id, like this:

```
org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [com.sample.model.User#f5a3483a-625e-446c-a8a9-91e18c222220]
```

Since there are multiple scenarios possible with this particular section, I would like to know which scenario this occurs, for which I need to know the query which caused it. How do I get it? I simply can't use show query because this only occurs in production.

Comment: analyse your prod logs, it will help to trace your code from where it happens.

Comment: Anlayzing the production logs is a pain as our system has very high concurrency.